# How to float left drawable with (hint) label in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using TextInputLayout and in which i set a drawableLeft and when i click on edittext the label is already floating up but i want to float the left drawable too with the label. How can i achieve , see the attached image...

Right now when i click on "Title" only leble is floating up but i want both should be floating "leftdrawable" and "label" when focused. And before to click it will look a normal line like "Service Date".

[image]

My code is below..

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_cardnum"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLeft"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_cardnums"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cardnumEditTexst"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="255"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="hello"
            android:drawableLeft="@null"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And in my code i'm setting an animation on onFocus so it goes on top with label

```
  final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.anims);
  final ImageView imgLeft = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLeft);

  final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cardnumEditTexst);
    et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            if (hasFocus)
            {
                if (et.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    imgLeft.startAnimation(animation);
                }
            } else
            {
                if (et.getText().length() == 0)
                    imgLeft.clearAnimation();
            }
        }
    });
```

And my animation will throw the image view on top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true"
     android:duration="200"
     android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear"
    >
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0%"
        android:fromYScale="0%"
        android:toXScale="60%"
        android:toYScale="60%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        />
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:startOffset="100"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-80%"/>

</set>
```

And by setting this i got, now floating is okay but see the **paddingLeft="35dp"**, i want to start it from 0th position see in the first image where "Title" is showing, i mean there should not be padding but if i will **remove** the paddingLeft the floating functionality loss.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to write your own implementation for that. The TextInputLayout uses [CollapsingTextHelper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/6ba61c5/design/src/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingTextHelper.java)  class to draw animated text onto layout's canvas. There is no room for customization as this class is internal.

Comment: @ S.D. i tried to customize but now i have a little problem only, i want to remove the leftPadding, so that user can input very starting, see the image

Comment: Just remove/set the left drawable when animation starts. [TextInputLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/6ba61c5/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.java) has a TextListener monitoring the EditText in it, and from here it fires animation.

Comment: do notice on imageview, if i'll going to remove/ set the padding on animation start where will go my imageview?

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anims);
final ImageView imgLeft = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLeft);

findViewById(R.id.cardnumEditTexst).setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            imgLeft.startAnimation(animation);
        } else {
            imgLeft.clearAnimation();
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0%"
        android:fromYScale="0%"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="60%"
        android:toYScale="60%" />

    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:startOffset="100"
        android:toYDelta="-80%" />

</set>
```

and set your layout like this...

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout_cardnum">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLeft"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_cardnums"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cardnumEditTexst"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="255"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="hello"
            android:drawableLeft="@null"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please see my edited question, i'm not getting well, see the image.